# Checking if a string contains a specific word C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am checking these strings to see if they contain the word "hi" and returning true if they do. otherwise i am returning false. the string "high up should return false but is returning true. How can i fix this?

```
    public static bool StartHi(string str)
    {            
        if (Regex.IsMatch(str, "hi"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartHi("hi there");    // -> true
        StartHi("hi");          // -> true
        StartHi("high up");     // -> false (returns true when i run)
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using word boundaries in your Regex?

Comment: I have not, how would i do that?

Comment: See this link: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html or AlexD's answer

Comment: `string.Contains` does not accept a regex, use `Regex.IsMatch(string, pattern)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try specifying [word boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordBoundary) (`\b`):

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(str, @"\bhi\b"))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private static bool CheckIfExists(string sourceText, string textToCheck)
    {
        return sourceText.Split(' ').Contains(textToCheck);
    }
```

Comment: So, Isn't a word a substring?

Answer (score 0):

This code will return True for "jumps" but not "jump" in sentence.

```
string sourceText = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy white dog.";
string textToCheck = "jump";
   if (sourceText.Split(' ').Contains(textToCheck))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Word \"" + textToCheck + "\" EXACTLY exists in sentence");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Word \"" + textToCheck + "\" doesn't exist in sentence");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```